# vmware : virtual port serial between 2 vm

Tags: linux, serial-port, debian, vmware, vmware-player

I'm on Windows 7.
I would like to connect 2 VM(ware) Debian by serial port.

First I'm trying to create the "reader" VM.
I tried to add a serial port like this :
- name : /dev/ttyS1
- This end is is the client.
- The other end is a virtual machine.

But my program cannot open the /dev/ttyS1 serial port (the programs succeed with a actual hardware serial port).

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two physical COM ports on the computer? Map 2 virtual machines to these ports, and connect ports with null modem.

Another thing I can think about is connecting two VM ports through host pipe, but I have never tried to do this.

Comment: I tried with usb_to_serial hardware, that's ok. But the aim is precisely to avoid additionnal hardware stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
You would need some sort of a proxy.
I did this with KVM a while ago and how it worked was like this:

serial -> socket (guest #1)
serial -> socket (guest #2)
python script connects to both sockets and acts as a proxy so to speak. When data comes from s1, it gets written onto s2 and vice versa. Used that for kernel debugging and it's slow but functional.

You could do the same on Windows with pipes
```